# What is the right way to record commands when using vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

When I invoke `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` and `vkCmdEndRenderPass` on the same `CommandBuffer`, Everything is fine.

If I call these two functions on different `CommandBuffer`s. I got an error says that `If commandBuffer is a primary command buffer, there must not be an active render pass instance.` And the document says `vkCmdEndRenderPass` must only be called inside of a render pass instance. I don't know exactly what a `render pass instance` really is. I guess I must call those two function on the same `CommandBuffer`. Doesn't that means I must record the entire frame before I can submit anything to the GPU to draw? Just don't feel right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A render pass is what you get back from `vkCreateRenderPass`; that is, a `VkRenderPass` object. Think of it like a class definition in your code.

A render pass *instance* is the period within a command buffer during which a specific render pass is active. For primary command buffers, this is the space between `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` and `vkCmdEndRenderPass` calls. For secondary command buffers, either the *entire* CB executes within a specific render pass (and a single subpass of that render pass) or *none of it* executes in a render pass. But either way, you can use the same `VkRenderPass` object to create multiple render pass instances.

If you want to record commands for the render pass from multiple threads, you use secondary command buffers. Indeed, allowing this is the main reason why secondary command buffers exist at all.

So you have a bunch of threads create a bunch of secondary command buffers, each of which inherits the render pass state from the primary CB. After building the secondary CBs, then the main thread creates a short primary command buffer that just uses `vkCmdExecuteCommands` to execute those secondary CBs. And then you submit the primary CB to the queue.